# How to return an empty Mat in a function for c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

now I have a function:

```
cv::Mat func(int number){
cv::Mat img;
...
if(number>=0)return img;
else if(number<0) return xxx;
}
```

Here, when `number<0` I want to return an empty Mat, but `return NULL;` or `return;` are incorrect. So how to how to return an empty Mat in a function?

Anyone can give some advises?

Comment: CvMat & Mat are different....  but anyway  declaring 
 cv::Mat matrix   means matrix  is empty  and you  can check  that with isempty function.   So just  return  matrix. If empty means  for  you  black pixels  then initialize it first and return  it.

Comment: @Ziri I have modified my question. You are right with returning the img directly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on what empty means to you, you can:
return default constructed `cv::Mat`

```
...
if(number>=0)return img;
else if(number<0) return cv::Mat{};
}
```

or create black (or any other color) `cv::Mat` with same `size` and `type` as your `img`

```
cv::Mat img;
...
if(number>=0)return img;
else if(number<0) return cv::Mat{img.size(), img.type(), cv::Scalar{0,0,0}};
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I just want a empty Mat like Ziri said above. Thank you also.